# How to type a constant with string-defined functions?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I have this TypeScript code:

```js
enum EVENT {
  FIRST_EVENT = "game:first_encounter",
}

const EventHandler: keyof typeof EVENT = {
    [EVENT.FIRST_EVENT]: (data: any) => {
        console.log(`Hello there, ${data.blue_player}`);
    }
}

const data = { blue_player: 'Blue McBlue', event: EVENT.FIRST_EVENT}
const eventName: EVENT = data.event;

EventHandler[eventName](data);
```

I have an error with `EventHandler` near the top.

```
Type '{ "game:first_encounter": (data: any) => void; }' is not assignable to type '"FIRST_EVENT"'
```

I also have an error of with `eventName` on the last line with:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAogajAcgFSgbwFBSgMQJIBKAysgPrxKoC8UARAOYCGEwAXAGYCWATgM4AupUAGMA9mBD9g3WgBoMAXwwYxIAbABuofgAlGIACYAbaaygBrYAE9R7KPysAHYLc3aoNTNmwBtCigA6fGIyf2QAXTMACgNGfkYzfSsASg8APnQsb2zVXlETAKNReiiAAx1gIyL7AAtpYFkoABI0WPiAgCMjMGBSRyNGK2kFUuSAbizsJSUVUTV+KDbGD3QoLp6+gaHuMwByACFu4CgAWWFDnt3G4C1JMzCgwhJyBBQlXIWb7URmNlhX6iLOKMAJfSQTDAwW66fTGaQ+MH8H4scIxYHjIA

See what I mean? How can I correctly type this?

Comment: The type declaration in `const EventHandler: keyof typeof Event` seems incomplete, and refers to the DOM `Event` type not to `EVENT`. What did you actually mean there?

Comment: Try omitting the type annotation and find out what TypeScript infers as the the type of the `EventHandler` variable.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, that's on me. I updated it

Comment: Thanks. Still it's not quite clear what you are trying to do. Can you describe in words the type that `EventHandler` should have?

Comment: @Bergi presumably it's the (common) pattern of mapping actions to functions (using a unique key for actions which is what the enum is for I assume?)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yes, probably - still I wanted the OP to describe the desired type in their own words as a way for them to arrive at the proper solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start typing `EventHandler` and figure this out.

First of all it's an object:

```
type EventHandlerType = {};
```

It has keys that are EVENTs

```
// Create a mapped type mapping events to anything
type EventHandlerType = { [e in EVENT]: any }
```

Every value is a function that takes a data parameter and returns void

```
// Create a mapped type mapping events to anything
type EventHandlerType = { [e in EVENT]: (data: any) => void };
```

Which should work in your code:

```
const EventHandler: { [key in EVENT]: (data: any) => void } = {
    [EVENT.FIRST_EVENT]: (data: any) => {
        console.log(`Hello there, ${data.blue_player}`);
    }
}
```

This is made simpler with the built in utility type `Record` which exists for these cases:

```
const EventHandler: Record<EVENT, (data: any) => void> = {
    [EVENT.FIRST_EVENT]: (data: any) => {
        console.log(`Hello there, ${data.blue_player}`);
    }
}
```

See [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) in the docs for more examples and a drill down.

Comment: I'd prefer `Record<EVENT, (data: {blue_player: string}) => void>`

Comment: @Bergi I considered (since it's what I use in my actual code) - I'll add that in, though didactically it has less value.

Comment: I see now. I understand. Is there a partial one? Some `EVENTS` might be abstracted out to other files where I can import them and spread them within the `EventHandler`...otherwise I am getting `Property '"EVENT.SECOND_EVENT"' is missing in type`

Comment: @GreenMtn you can put a question mark in front of a type to make it optional (so in this case `{ [e in EVENT]?: ...`). There is a helper for that as well (called, Partial<>). So in your case it'd just be wrapping the whole type in `Partial<>`.

Comment: I see.  Yeah it makes sense. Then in `EventHandler[eventName](data)` I get: `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'`

Comment: @GreenMtn good! that's TypeScript making a runtime error a compile time error doing it's job! It's telling you that you should check the handler exists before calling it (or explicitly ignore failures). You can use optional chaining for that: `EventHandler[eventName].?(data)` if you don't care about the key not existing but still don't want a runtime error.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I see. Am I doing something wrong? I get syntax errors https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAogajAcgFSgbwFBSgMQJIBKAysgPrxKoC8UARAOYCGEwAXAGYCWATgM4AupUAGMA9mBD9g3WgBoMAXwwYxIAbABuofgAlGIACYAbaaygAFRt36dGRgDxooAbQDWwAJ5ROIWAhQAugD8ZgAUBoz8jGb6HgCUUFQAfFAaopwGUAopNJjY2M4UKAB0+MRkRcgBYRFRMSDxiSl5+a2qvKImxUai9KEABjrARj1Q-AAW0sCyUAAkaLWMxQBGRmDApAAORowe0gr9cQDcWPlKSiqiavxQi4noUKvrWzt73GYA5ABCa8BQALLCH7rD4zYBaSRmSqlQgkcj+ZBKdo3cHaRDMNh+Sj3RbFVGSE4YGAQ3T6YzSZz4-jolgBYpBcKRRjHIA

Comment: The ? goes before the . so `EventHandler[eventName]?.(data);` is valid but `EventHandler[eventName].?(data);` is a syntax error.